# How to access global variables assigned in one function in another function in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular8, angular4-forms

I am new to angular.

I have form-control.component.ts file
in that I have declared these 3 variables globally

```
 name1:any;
 pw :any';
 g :any;
```

these 3 variables I have used in one function

```
displayAccountInfo(account:Account)
{
 this.name1=account.name;
 this.pw=account.password;
 this.g=account.gender;
}
```

I want to display value of these 3 varible in  ClickMe() function

```
result:string;

ClickMe():void {
  this.result =' *saved dataItems:  ' + this.name1 +this.pw +this.g ;
}
```

but I am getting these output

```
 *saved dataItems: undefined undefined undefined
```

I have to display values which get assigned to these variable in displayAccountInfo() function

I have called displayAccountInfo() in Save method

```
 Save():void{
 let account:Account=this.registerform.value;
 account.languages=this.checkedList;
 this.displayAccountInfo(account);

}
```

And these is entire file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Account}  from './account.entity'
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-form-control',
 templateUrl: './form-control.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./form-control.component.css']
})
export class FormControlComponent implements OnInit {

genders:any;
languages:any;
registerform:FormGroup;
checkedList:string[];
certificates:any;

name1:any;
pw :any;
g :any;

constructor(
 private formbuilder:FormBuilder) {  }

 ngOnInit() {

      this.checkedList=[];

      this.certificates=[
        {value:'c1' ,display: 'Microsoft'},
        {value:'c2' ,display: 'Oracle'},
        {value:'c3' ,display: 'Angular'},
        {value:'c4' ,display: 'Java'},
      ];

      this.genders=[
        {value:'F' ,display:'Female'},
        {value:'M' ,display:'Male'}
      ];

      this.languages=[
        {id:'1' ,name:'C#'},
        {id:'2' ,name:'Java'},
        {id:'3' ,name:'typescript'},
        {id:'4' ,name:'Html'}
      ];

    this.registerform=this.formbuilder.group({
        name:'',
        password:'',
        gender:this.genders[0].value,
        languages:[],
        certificates:[]
    });


  }

Save():void{
 let account:Account=this.registerform.value;
 account.languages=this.checkedList;
 this.displayAccountInfo(account);

}

displayAccountInfo(account:Account)
{
 this.name1=account.name;
 this.pw=account.password;
 this.g=account.gender;

  for(var i=0; i< account.languages.length; i++)
  {
    var lang=account.languages[i];
  }

  for(var j=0; j< account.certificates.length; j++)
  {
    var cer=account.certificates[i];
  }

 }

 Checkboxchange(option,event)
{
if(event.target.checked)
{
  this.checkedList.push(option.id);
}
else
{
  for(var i=0;i<this.languages.length;i++)
  {
      if(this.checkedList[i]==option.id)
      {
        this.checkedList.splice(i,1);
      }
  }
} 
}


result:string;

ClickMe():void {
  this.result =' *saved dataItems:  ' + this.name1 +this.pw +this.g ;
 }


}
```

Comment: maybe you didnt call displayAccountInfo first?

Comment: Can you please share your entire formcontrol.ts? Your code looks very unstructured and this is not how you're supposed to use angular.

Comment: If something is being clicked and displayed, that are tasks of a Component. So the code should be inside of a component (some.component.ts), inside of that component class you should then change the 3 variables name1, pw and g. You should not be using global variables at all for this.

Comment: my code is inside form-control.component.ts file @Robin De Schepper

Comment: Ok, thanks, can you confirm by adding a console.log at the end of `displayAccountInfo` that the `this.name1`, `this.pw` and `this.g` properties are set to the values you expect? Because perhaps the `account` that you send in there is not the value you think it is.

Comment: yes.it is showing correct value with console.log @Robin De Schepper

Comment: Ok, and then when after you've seen the console print, you call the clickMe and this.name1, this.pw and this.g are suddenly undefined?

Comment: yup..scope of that variables ended in displayAccountInfo() function and i am unable to fetch that values in ClickMe() function. @Robin De Schepper

Comment: That's incorrect, the scope of these variables is the component's class. The value of `this.name1` is accessible from anywhere in the component's class, including the `Save`, `displayAccountInfo` and `ClickMe` methods. You must be making another mistake. If all of your code is inside of `FormControlComponent`, and you set `this.name1` inside of `displayAccountInfo`, then it will be in scope at `ClickMe`

Comment: I made you a stackblitz to prove that functions inside of a component class can access the instance's variables https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pbjxm. Try to get this working in your project and adapt from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create `formcontrol.ts` as followed

```
export var formcontrol = {
  name1: 'name',
  pw: 'pw',
  g: 'gender',
```

And then you can simlpy import it and use it

```
import { formcontrol } from 'your/path/formcontrol';

displayAccountInfo(account:Account) {
 formcontrol.name1 = account.name;
 formcontrol.pw = account.password;
 formcontrol.g = account.gender;
}
```

I personally would not use it that way i would create a service that would serve this vars for me.
[Here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) you can read more about angular services

Comment: I have to display values which get assigned to these variable in displayAccountInfo() function @Norbert Bartko

Comment: You can do that with `formcontrol.name1 = 'new name';`

Comment: then output is *`saved dataItems: name pw gender`  @Norbert Bartko

Answer (score 0):

Assing default values to globals

```
 name1:any = '';
 pw :any = '';
 g :any = '';
```

Comment: then output is blank    *saved dataItems:   @Sachila Ranawaka